# How can i display a C-style array in visual studio watch without showing its address

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, watch-window

I'm looking for a easy way to display a C-style-array in the visual studio watch window without showing its address.

Unfortunately, the [format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp) `na` does only cover pointers.

F.e. see this array definition

```
int a[] = { 1,2 };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's obvious but an easy workaround the somewhat narrow definition of `na` is to cast to a pointer. For the example in the question:

[image]

The only drawback is that the array length has to be specified manually and that it's way too expressive.

However, what's nice is that this also works with [natvis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010"> 
  <Type Name="S">
    <DisplayString>a={(int*)a,2na}</DisplayString> 
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

[image]